# Cannot check out using paypal sandbox account for testing

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can i test my Paypal cart checkout using my sandbox account. I am using the javascript version of Paypal **"add to cart"** buttons and have specified **data-env="sandbox"**.

It takes me to **"https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION..."**.

I dont know whether it should go to **"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION.."**

and i cannot login with my sandbox account to complete the test checkout.

P.S I have cleared  cookies.

Comment: Give us your php and js details. What method are you using to send data to paypal. And is your shopping cart hosted with paypal, or are you forwarding shopping cart details to paypal for checkout. Be detailed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `<form>` your `action` attribute should go to the `sandbox.paypal.com` URL.